# rest api with gerrit configured with http authentication

Tags: gerrit

I have a working gerrit installation, the only thing is, gerrit is configured with HTTP authentication backend, and nginx handle the authentication.

Now, I want to use gerrit restapi (just to set Verified label via curl as a specific user). for that I need to use http password generated by gerrit in setting panel. so you can see the problem. 
there is two different password. 
first I try to set same password for both, (nginx password is in my control, gerrit is not) 
then I change try to create a new location for /a/ (gerrit prefix for authentication) and remove the nginx password on that route, yet no luck. 
the final nginx config is :

```
location /a/ {
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8118;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        auth_basic "Gerrit";
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
}

location / {
        proxy_pass        http://127.0.0.1:8118;
        proxy_set_header  X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header  Host $host;
        auth_basic "Gerrit";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/conf.d/gerrit.htpasswd;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
        proxy_pass_header  Authorization;
}
```

my gerrit config is :

```
[gerrit]
        basePath = git
        canonicalWebUrl = http://gerrit.example.com/
[database]
        type = postgresql
        hostname = 127.0.0.1
        database = reviewdb
        username = gerrit2
[index]
        type = LUCENE
[auth]
        type = HTTP
[sendemail]
        smtpServer = mail.vada.ir
        from = ${user} Code Review <git@vada.ir>
        smtpUser = git@vada.ir
        smtpPass = T7SMkUYRqMP

[container]
        user = gerrit2
        javaHome = /usr/lib/jvm/java-7-openjdk-amd64/jre
[sshd]
        listenAddress = *:29418
[httpd]
        listenUrl = proxy-http://127.0.0.1:8118/
[cache]
        directory = cache
[plugins]
        allowRemoteAdmin = true
```

changing the gerrit authentication is only an option if we can protect it from registration.

Thank you.

Comment: How does your `gerrit.config` look like?

Comment: I found thge solution, but I add the config to the post too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the normal (basic auth) is not working with api in my setup. but using the [digets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digest_access_authentication) authentication is working without problem.